# tipauni: Package fontspec Error: The font "tipauni-newcm-regular" cannot be found

Tags: tipa, tipauni

When trying to compile the following, I get the error `Package fontspec Error: The font "tipauni-newcm-regular" cannot be found.`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipauni}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I am using XeLaTeX, and have `fontspec` installed. I've installed the `newcomputermodern` package and run `fc-cache`. Since the document doesn't actually have anything in it, it's something that happens when loading the `tipauni` package, and not due to something that happens when actually attempting to render an IPA symbol in unicode.

How can I get the right font installed?

Edit:
In the meantime, I've been able to get it to work with the old default, Charis SIL, by doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[documentfont=CharisSIL]{tipauni}
\begin{document}
    \textipa{@} % for example
\end{document}
```

That's working for now, but it'd still be nice to know how to use the New Computer Modern option.

Comment: are you on linux?

Comment: Nope, Windows 10.

Comment: is your tex system up-to-date? Which one do you use?

Comment: I'm using MikTeX. `xelatex --version` tells me that I'm on version 4.10.

Comment: the installation of tipauni in miktex is faulty. The two .fontspec-files (`tipauni-newcm-regular.fontspec` and `tipauni-newcm-book.fontspec`) are missing. You should report that at the miktex bug tracker.